# How to compute the output impedance of this current source that makes part of a OPAMP

Tags: circuit-analysis

Here's the schematic:

[image]

i would like to find the output impedance of current source IF1 (seen on that rectangle covering a led, T6 and 2 resistors).

Now, i already have the values of IF1,RF2,RF1, Q-points of all transistors and also gains and output/input impedance's of all 3 stages . I believe to be able to solve this problem if i put use the pi-hybrid model but then what?

Would like to add, i also know the base/colector/emitter current of T6

Comment: If you know all these things you claim you know (eg, base/collector/emitter current), please add then to the question. It will make it clear that you are not trying to have EESE here solve your homework, and make it easier for someone answering.

Comment: Take a look at this examples https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/380543/finding-the-output-resistance-of-npn-current-mirror/380623#380623 and here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/342859/bjt-common-base-output-resistance-derivation/342989#342989